# ASP.Net Identify "Invalid token" on password reset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, change-password

I'm working on an MVC5 web application where membership is invitation-only, so user accounts have to be pre-created by an administrator. The account is populated with the user's email address which also serves as the user name, and the account is created without a password.

```
    private async Task CreateAndNotifyUser(string emailAddress)
        {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = emailAddress, Email = emailAddress};
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(result.Errors.First());
        await SendNotificationEmail(user.Id);
        }
```

The user gets a notification email, with a link to click, which contains an email verification token. The token is generated like this:

```
    private async Task SendNotificationEmail(string userId)
        {
        var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
        var emailModel = new VerificationTokenEmailModel
            {
            ApplicationName = "MVC5 Application",
            CallbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "UserAdministration", new {userId, code}, Request.Url.Scheme),
            InformationUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
            VerificationToken = code
            };
        var emailBody = razor.RunCompile("NewUserInvitation.cshtml", typeof(VerificationTokenEmailModel), emailModel);
        await userManager.SendEmailAsync(userId, "Invitation", emailBody);
        }
```

When the user opens their email and clicks the link, I mark their email as "confirmed" via the UserManager, then I generate a password reset token for the user, and redirect to the ResetPassword action in the AccountController, like so:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
            return View("Error");
        var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(result.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
        var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
        code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
        return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "Account", new {code});
        }
```

However, when the user enters their email and two matching passwords, they receive the error "Invalid token" in the validation summary.

I read in other questions that this is potentially a problem with HTTP encoding of the token, however I've examined the tokens produced and they don't appear to contain + or space characters. I've tried both with and without this line:

```
code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
```

I've been at it for two days and I can't find out why this is happening. I'm even more puzzled as to why the email verification token works just fine, but the password reset token doesn't. Any ideas, anyone?

UPDATE: 2016-07-18

I've tried registering a user with the normal `Register()` action, and following through the sequence of confirming the email address. If at that point I manually activate the `/Account/ForgotPassword` action, the password reset works. So clearly there is some difference that I haven't twigged. I can't see it for looking and it's probably something simple-but-obscure.

Comment: I know its been years. Having the same problem. Did you solve it?